# How to disable the stack trace in c++ glog?

Tags: c++11, glog

I applied Glog to output some runtime information in my code, and I want to disable the stack trace function to protect the detail of the code. But I find the Glog is default to track the stack trace and log it to std err or log file, and there is no `FLAGS_xx` to disable it.

And I tried to `#undef` some of the stack trace related macro such as `HAVE_STACKTRACE`, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any elegant method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL void InstallFailureFunction(void (*fail_func)());` to install a customized function to output some customized information instead of the stack trace.

But in the std output there is still a line `*** Check failure stack trace: ***` to remind the user, and I don't know how to shut it down. It's not elegant enough.